# Parsing compressed blob using Apache Tika

Tags: compression, blob, apache-tika

I've been trying to detect and parse using Apache Tika a large byte array I retrieved using Spring JDBC from rows of *compressed* blob records. These records originally came from IBM DB2/Mainframe and then migrated to Oracle 11g/Unix. The first few hex values are

```
8c d0 9e 45 00 17 2a 96 86 70 00 12 2a 5c c8 10 80 0f 00 03 00 f8 fb 97 00 80 81 86
```

I've tried the various Compressor and Package Parsers of Tika but it apparently cannot detect what type of format it is. Ultimately, when decompressed, the byte arrays should be of the Word.Document.8 format. The hex signature of MSWord is D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 00, and Tika can detect this of course.

Is anyone familiar with the hex signature above? I was wondering if I can just reverse engineer the hex signatures to determine the compression algorithm used - how should one go about it?

Comment: Not all compression formats have a consistent header at the start, so you might just want to try running various decompressors on it until one yields the right magic on the output

Comment: The preponderance of zeros and other common bytes indicates that this is a header of some sort.  It is not yet at the compressed data portion, which should appear random.